# Including JS file in View In YII

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii-events

I want to load the `JS`  file in view to avoid heavy-loading of my application. I am using this `JS` file for `CgrdView` in view. SO i tried this:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/assets/9d419b82/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.0.127'
);
```

in My view header.
But i am getting the error:**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**
As stated, i want to load jquery.ba-bbq.js file in view for CgriView, but i am not able to load that.
Instead, i use following, but dont know is the efficient way to load or not.

```
<script src="/assets/9d419b82/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.0.127" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And is working when i load that in layouts, but this is not the efficient way.

FYI: I am working with `cgridview` search-box to post the search-box entry to my controller.

Comment: Don't put your custom files in the assets directory, that's for auto generated Yii files, it's much better to use your own directory (e.g. /webroot/js/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.0.127). [Info Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/#hh4) you might find useful.

Comment: Exactly, i want to autoload the js file by cgridview...

Comment: yii will autoload its own files when it needs them, you should never reference the assets directories? did yii create `jquery.ba-bbq.js`, or did you create that file?

Comment: I think, YII Owns jquery.ba-bbq.js. If not i dont know whats next.. suggest me..! Any help will be acceptable.

Comment: Doesn't CGridView load ba-bbq.js automagically?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do manually here?

Comment: @ernie Is there any method to load that JS file in View without including that in layouts..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bbq script is available as a core script and registering it will also load jquery.js. So to use bbq you simply need to do this:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('bbq');
```

The assets folder is dynamic in nature, and it is used to store scripts, css, images in a web-accessible directory. It is automatically populated by the various Yii widgets, and also when you call `registerCoreScript`. Because of these reasons [and more](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/) you shouldn't be relying on the assets folder to include js, css, images, but instead let the framework include it for you.

---

I couldn't find a list of the core packages in the docs, but it can be seen in the source file: [*framework/web/js/packages.php*](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/js/packages.php).

---

Incase you want this in a view with a `CGridView`, then let me tell you that `CGridView` loads this script automatically, and you don't have to register it again.

Comment: I am confused little bit. Is the part where the **bbq** file is included is hidden in the view-page while we are viewing as page-sorce? I mean to say that, what if we want to see the page-source ? Is this really converted into **<script src="/assets/9d419b82/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.0.127" type="text/javascript"></script>**?? Suggest me the real differences..!
FYI: Your suggestion is not working for me.. that is still unable to load that file.

Comment: yes it should, i don't have the v= part though. can you show me your actual view file? and what exactly do you mean by real difference, and difference between what?

Comment: Is **Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('bbq');** ===  **<script src="/assets/9d419b82/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.0.127" type="text/javascript"></script>** ?

Comment: no `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('bbq');` will probably get you something like `<script src="/assets/somerandomstring/jquery.ba-bbq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. i.e. `somerandomstring` can be anything, it could be 9d419b82 or something else. can you tell me again, do you already have a gridview in this view?

Comment: Yes, i have a **CGridView** in My view file, that has some columns and a row with search-box for each of the column, when i write **<script src="/assets/9d419b82/jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.0.127" type="text/javascript"></script>** in my view file, its working. But when i use **Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('bbq');** or something, is not working. I dont actually know where i am stacked.

Comment: ok, have you tried not adding the js in layout/view, and only defining the gridview? because as has already been said gridview loads bbq by itself, so you don't have to include bbq again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22377/discussion-between-tnc-and-bool-dev)